# Generate a heatmap using bokeh

Tags: python, heatmap, bokeh

I've got a `DataFrame` that looks like:

```
        F130    L151    G211    B615 ....
F130      84     0       0       0  
L151       0    2158     0       0  
G211       0     0      2323     1      
B615       0     2       0      1485    
 .
 .
 .
```

And I would like to use bokeh in order to generate a heatmap using `DataFrame` rows as x axis and `DataFrame` columns as y axis.

Does any one have an idea how to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: use DataFrame.stack() to create x, y and value columns. Then plot that.

Comment: Can you give me an example with the 4 rows dataframe described above, thanks in advance

Comment: I managed to do it using df.stack(), thanks a lot @LukeCanavan

Comment: Could you post how to do it with `df.stack`?